# php find and replace string after specific char

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a long string that contain few "*" chars, I want to find all those chars and replace them+the 8 chars after them, And replace them with anther string. What is the best way to do this? this is how i tried to do:

```
 $over_string=strlen($story)-1;
 for ($i=0; $i<$over_string; $i++){
if($story[$i]=='*'){
     $id_substr=substr($story, $i+1,8);
     $name_player_change=some_function($id_substr);
     $id_to_replace='*'.$id_substr;
     $name_to_place='<a href="#">'.$name_player_change.'</a>';
     $story=str_replace($id_to_replace,$name_to_place,$story);
}//if
  }//for
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what the original string looks like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$story = preg_replace('/\*.{8}/', $name_to_place, $story);
```

should get you where you want to go.

or if you want to replace the guts of the link with the 8 matching characters after the * then you can use.

```
$story = preg_replace('/\*(.{8})/', '<a href="#">$1</a>', $story);
```